# An exception occurred in the driver: could not find driver SYMFONY

Tags: php, xampp, symfony, composer, symfony4

estoy tratando de crear una base de datos en symfony y me sale este error:
Antes que nada voy a comentar que programa estoy uilizando:

php version -> 8.0.19.

xampp

symfony version ->5.4.8

composer version -> 2.3.5

yo ya tengo creado la base de datos en phpMyAdmin
y tambien tengo la URL vinculado en el .env

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root@localhost:3306/productosreact?serverVersion=5.7&charset=utf8mb4"
```

al hacer:

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:create
```

me sale el siguiente error de la imagen:

[image: error al hacer php bin/console doctrine:database:create]

ante este problema estuve investigando en google y ninguno de las soluciones propuesta me resuelve este problema, voy a comentar las siguientes soluciones que encontre:

instalar mysql -> ya lo tengo instalado pero no soluciono

tener desomentando la extension=pdo_mysql en php.ini -> lo tengo descomentado pero no me soluciono el problema

tener instalado Drivers for PHP for SQL Server -> no me soluciono

mucho de los problemas comunes que habia es que se ponia mal la URL que conecta con la base de datos, intente de maneras distintas como poniendo una contraseña y usuario pero tampoco me soluciono, lo mas raro es que intente desde mi otra computadora y sin tocar nada ya me creo la base de datos, en esta computadora que estoy intentando hacer esto tengo el problema.La diferencia es que tengo window 11 y en la otra window 10(es de la otra computadora) nose si varia algo pero igual lo comento.

dejo mi configuracion de doctrine.yaml

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'

    # IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version,
    # either here or in the DATABASE_URL env var (see .env file)
    #server_version: '13'
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
    auto_mapping: true
    mappings:
        App:
            is_bundle: false
            dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
            prefix: 'App\Entity'
            alias: App
           when@test:
            doctrine:
               dbal:
                  # "TEST_TOKEN" is typically set by ParaTest
                  dbname_suffix: '_test%env(default::TEST_TOKEN)%'
      when@prod:
        doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: false
        query_cache_driver:
            type: pool
            pool: doctrine.system_cache_pool
        result_cache_driver:
            type: pool
            pool: doctrine.result_cache_pool

framework:
    cache:
        pools:
            doctrine.result_cache_pool:
                adapter: cache.app
            doctrine.system_cache_pool:
                adapter: cache.system
```

tambien instala y desinstale XAMPP , PHP , SYMFONY Y COMPOSER cambiando de versiones a esto

Answer (score 1):

En mi caso modifique el archivo php.ini, y habilite quitando el ; en extension=pdo_mysql.
Si eso no funciona o genera más errores correr estos dos comandos:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove php-common

sudo apt-get install php-common php-mysql php-cli
```